# Getting error while using tabhost in 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Hello i am using the tabhost in my application it works fine in 4.0 and up but when i try to run it in 2.3.3 it returns me a null pointer exception and force closes the application

here is the code i am getting error in :

```
        TextView t = new TextView(this) ;
            t=  (TextView) getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        t.setTextColor(Color. parseColor("#ffffff"));

        if (i == 0) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00aedb"));

        else tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0d82df"));
```

this is my logcat output :

`05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moneyminder/com.example.moneyminder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.example.moneyminder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-16 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  ... 11 more`

Comment: I can't find `null pointer exception` in your logcat.please post your full logcat.

Comment: 12:29:27.009: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: please let us know what is at line 78 in your MainActivity.java

Comment: @MehulJoisar yes sure on line 78 i have : t.setTextColor(Color. parseColor("#ffffff"));

Comment: as per the error your text view is referencing to null.

Comment: @MehulJoisar yes you are right , but what should i do to remove the error

Comment: I'm not getting any idea why it is giving NPE only on 2.3.3